# Integer vs decimal sales in Shopify?

Tags: variables, integer, shopify, square

Does anyone know the programming issue that allows some companies to be able to track inventory by decimal place for weight based products such as cheese and meats vs only solid inventory values?

Square allows us small retailers to use weight based pricing and even variable weight/price barcodes which makes checkout an order of magnitude faster, especially with new staff. Shopify does not support this.

There is a third party app that attempts to do this but it also can not accurately adjust our shopify inventory because they simply do not allow an inventory count to be a decimal place.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would assign a weight to your cheese or meat. For example, 1 gram. A small enough unit right. So if you had 10 kilos of meat in stock, you might sell that meat by the gram. Someone buys 400 grams of meat, they pay the price that you set for that variant of meat, some unit price per gram.

You cannot put a decimal as a quantity in a shopping cart, but you can put in an integer value representing weight. I think if you keep that straight, it all works out fine.

Comment: David, Thank you for responding. We did do that at one point, but it adds a number of other hurdles and issues when it comes to reporting. Just wondering, why can you not put a decimal as a quantity? Database issues?

Comment: There is no such thing as selling 3.45 of something. Or 1.99 or 0.34 or 17.54. Shopping carts like Shopify are set to work off the quantity being an integer. 

1 bag
2 t-shirts
13 cans of juice

I get it though. The POS at a Grocery store sells 1.4 pounds of oranges to a customer, without complaint. 

All I know if you have to adjust to using weight as an integer quantity and charge per unit weight in Shopify...